# Renderizar json al hacer click a un boton en React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks, jsonobject

estoy practicando React pero tengo un problema. Al querer renderizar objetos de un json con un evento, no logro que lo haga.

Este es el codigo donde hago el llamado al json. La respuesta la da bien, pero al momento de hacer el return, me da error y me dice que no se pueden leer las propiedades en undefined. Esto pasa con  la img, name y type.

Si elimino PokemonItems, funciona bien y sale en la consola lo que se pide, pero cuando quiero renderizarlo no sirve.

````
import { PokemonItems } from "./PokemonItems";


export function PokemonApiCall() {

    const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);
    const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState('');


    useEffect(() => {
        searchPokemon()
    }, []);

    const letPokemon = async (e) => {
        setPokemon(e.target.value)
    }

    const searchPokemon = async () => {

        let url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemon}`

        let respuesta = await fetch(url, {
            'method': 'GET',
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        let json = await respuesta.json();

        setPokemons(json);

        console.log(pokemons)

    };

    return (
        <>
            <div className="search.poemon">
                <input type="text"
                    placeholder="Escribe el nombre del pokemon"
                    onChange={letPokemon} /> <br />
                <button
                    onClick={searchPokemon}>Buscar</button>
            </div>
            <PokemonItems
                img={pokemons.sprites.front_default}
                name={pokemons.name}
                type={pokemons.types.type}
                weight={pokemon.weight}>

            </PokemonItems>
        </>
    );
} ```


Gracias de ante mano :D
````

Comment: pokemos string  asi lo definistes en el use estates por lo que que todo lo que pases se hara cast to string

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres

Comment: Muestra tu componente `</PokemonItems>`

Comment: porque ejecutas la función `searchPokemon` en useEffect si hasta entonces no se ha hecho la búsqueda del Pokémon